# yarn install Angular

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg

I clone the angular repository but when trying to download the dependencies with the recommended command **yarn** I have an error:

Error text output console:

```sh
yarn install v1.18.0
$ node tools/yarn/check-yarn.js
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "graceful-fs@4.2.2" is incompatible with requested version "graceful-fs@~3.0.2"
warning Resolution field "graceful-fs@4.2.2" is incompatible with requested version "graceful-fs@^3.0.0"
warning Resolution field "graceful-fs@4.2.2" is incompatible with requested version "graceful-fs@~1.2.0"
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.5.1-linux.tar.gz: Request failed \"406 Not Acceptable\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/andrusd/Escritorio/Files/angular/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: the log says there was some error while trying to download this package `https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.5.1-linux.tar.gz`

Comment: what yarn version do you use ?

Comment: @pbachman yarn 1.18.0

Comment: @Manish Exactly the log says that this file could not be downloaded. My problem is how can I solve it, why does this happen?

Comment: @AndrusDiaz there was an issue with the same dependency but with yarn version 1.16.0, should work with 1.18.0 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31902

Answer (score 1):

There is an workaround for this error:

> An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.5.1-linux.tar.gz: Request failed
>   \"406 Not Acceptable\"".

Step 1: Remove following two scripts from `packages.json`

```
   1. `preinstall`

   2. `presetup`
```

Step 2: Install packages using `npm` with command `npm install`

Step 3: And now, run the `yarn setup` command to install all the dependencies, boilerplate, stackblitz, zips and run dgeni on the docs.

Step 4: Finally run the command `yarn start` and this the solution for the time being